# Why is no data written to existing Excel file using openpyxl based on matching columns?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have the following code:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="openpyxl")

file = f"{data_folder}\DIS_Ultimo_RWS_Decompositie4.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(file, data_only=False)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
writer.workbook = book

bouwdelen = book["Bouwdelen"]
data = bouwdelen.values

# Skip one row (second row in Excel sheet is the actual header)
next(data)

# Get the existing columns in the sheet and their corresponding indices
columns = [c for c in next(data)[0:] if c is not None]
# Set the column names as keys and indices as values
columns_dict = {c: i+1 for i, c in enumerate(columns)}

# Change order of the dataframe columns according to column order of the Excel file
def reorder_columns(df, column_order):
    try:
        # Get the list of columns that exist in both the DataFrame and the column_order list
        existing_columns = list(filter(lambda col: col in df.columns, column_order))

        # Reindex the DataFrame using the desired column order
        df = df.reindex(columns=existing_columns)

        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

data_verwijderen = reorder_columns(data_verwijderen, columns)    

# Insert the rows of the dataframe to the target columns in the Excel file

for column_source, col_idx in columns_dict.items():
    if column_source in data_verwijderen.columns:
        for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(data_verwijderen[column_source].values, start=3):
            bouwdelen.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=row_data)
                    
book.save(file)
```

For some reason the data from my dataframe is not written to my existing Excel file.

If I replace some lines of code with the following code it works:

```
for column_source, col_idx in columns_dict.items():
    for column_df in data_verwijderen.columns[0:]:
        if column_source == column_df:
            for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(data_verwijderen[column_df].values, start=3):
                bouwdelen.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=row_data)  
        else:
            continue
```

However, this seems to be very time consuming.

Is there a better more efficient way?

Comment: Why are you creating an index of columns from the worksheet values? Accessing individual values in a data frame is very slow, you need a better way of comparing which cells need replacing. I speak Dutch but I really don't understand what you're trying to do. You might be able to do this directly in Pandas with a merge.

Comment: I try to write data from my dataframe into columns of my existing Excel-file based on column name matching. Does openpyxl contain merge functionality?